# Node js url being requested multiple times

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node js. I am trying to import a save a large CSV file into mongoDB using node js. My method name is '**saveCSVintoDB**'. I am using csvtojson converter in this method to parse the file. As the file has more than 1 million records, the converter takes around 2 mins to parse the complete file. Meanwhile, My node js method '**saveCSVintoDB**' is being requested again and the parsing starts all over again.I don't want this to happen. I don't face this problem with smaller files as they are parsed much faster and the next request takes over from there on.

The problem is only while waiting for about 2 mins while the parsing happens. I don't understand this behavior. I am stuck with this for a long time. Can some body please explain this and suggest some possible alternative?

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: Can post some code? it is difficult to guess what's going on without looking at the code.

Comment: HI, Please find below the code. I have removed the saving into the mongodb part for clear reading.

Comment: router.post('/saveCollection', function(req, res,next) {
 console.log("col name:"+req.param("collName")); 
 var fileStream=fs.createReadStream(req.files.myFile.path);
 var csvConverter=new Converter({constructResult:false});
csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function()
{
 console.log('file completely parsed:');
 res.send({success:true});
}); 
console.log('before parsing');
fileStream.pipe(csvConverter); 

});

Comment: It is taking 2 mins between the logs 'before parsing' and 'file completely parsed:'.  And the request for method 'saveCollection' was triggered again in the meantime.

Comment: ok, is `saveCSVintoDB` called inside the anonymous function called on `end_parsed` or it is called outside it, near `fileStream.pipe(csvConverter);` ?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. I forgot to mention. I have renamed the methodname to 'saveCollection'.It is the main router method(check my earlier comment). So saveCSVintoDB  is no longer there. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: saveCSVintoDB  is renamed to SaveCollection. both are same actually

Comment: yes, I got your problem. I guess since you are not responding within certain time, the request is getting timed out and another request is being fired. You can try to increase the timeout and see if it helps

Comment: Hi Anurag, I thought so. But my request/response timeout is much longer. I had set it to 5 mins. Moreover, If it was a timeout case, it would have thrown a 'Response timedout' error which I am handling.  Also, What is beyond me is- why is it calling the 'same' request again after 2 mins?  I am using expressjs with node. Could it be the 'express' behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are catching timeout exception and why it is not being catched. It is not a 'express' behavior but defined in node. I have updated my answer with a work around. Have a look if it works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a timestamp to check when it is being requested the second time:

```
 console.log("got request @" + new  Date());
```

Since processing is taking time, the request is getting timed out and hence another request is being fired. You need to increase the timeout interval.

In vanilla JS:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { ... });
server.timeout = 120000;
```

If you are using Express then you can use Connect Middleware for Timeout support:

```
var timeout = express.timeout // express v3 and below
var timeout = require('connect-timeout'); //express v4

app.use(timeout(120000));
```

---

**Edit**: Handling the multiple request issue:

Most of the answers on SO hint that second request is made for favicon. But I checked on my local machine that this is not the case with the second request made after interval of around 2 minute by printing the `req.url` which points to the same page which in your case will be `/saveCollection`.

I can suggest a hack which worked on my local machine:

- Send headers: `res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });` upon request. This will buy us 2 minutes time.
- Now setup a interval which will keep feeding browser every 2 minutes with dummy data.
- When the computation is completed remove the interval, send the actual result and close the response.

Here's an example:

```
    router.post('/saveCollection', function(req, res,next) { 
      console.log("col name:"+req.param("collName"));   
      var fileStream=fs.createReadStream(req.files.myFile.path); 
      var csvConverter=new Converter({constructResult:false});
      csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function() { 
        console.log('file completely parsed:'); 
        clearInterval(si);
        res.write(", 'success':true}");
        res.end();
      });

      i = 0;
      var si = setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        res.write(",'dummy" + i + "' : 'piece'");
      }, 1000 * 60); //this should be kept a little less than two minutes

      console.log('before parsing'); 
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      res.write("{'dummy':'piece'");
      fileStream.pipe(csvConverter);    
    });
```

There is no other way to do this that I can think of. Even if you ignore the second request, still the first request will expire and browser will probably show an error.

There is another work around, start computing and send a response back as soon as computing starts and then use sockets to check the status.

Comment: Webserver timeout Doc: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback